# I want to know whether Z3 supports that a input file includes an another file

Tags: z3

I have two files, one is variable definition file, the other is formula file. Could you tell me how to insert the variable definition file into formula file. In yices, we can use "(include "file")" to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Z3 does not have an `include` command. However, you can use `cat` and pipes for doing what you want. For example, suppose you have the files `def.smt2` and `form.smt2`. Then, you can use the following command for concatenating and then invoking Z3.

```
  cat def.smt2 form.smt2 | z3 -in -smt2
```

The option `-in` tells z3 to use the standard input, and `-smt2` that the input is in SMT 2.0 format.